# How to retrieve data from model that current user created and list it for another model's field in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-model-field

Let us imagine that I have two models.
First model contains curse details and user that created this course

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and my second model is:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    course = models.OneToOneField(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # 
    # inside the course I want my APIVIEW to list only the courses that current user created. 
    # OnetoOne relationship does not solve the problem. 

    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, null=False, default=GOZLEMEDE,max_length=20)
    tariffs = models.FloatField(max_length=5,null=False,default=0.00)
    continues_off = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My serializers for both Models:

```
class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Lesson
        fields = ('course', 'status', 'tariffs', 'continues_off', 'user_profile')

        def create(self, validated_data):

            lesson = models.Lesson.objects.create(
                course = validated_data['course'],
                status = validated_data['status'],
                tariffs=validated_data['tariffs'],
                continues_off=validated_data['continues_off'],
                user_profile=validated_data['user_profile']
            )
            return lesson

class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializers Course content"""
    class Meta:
        model = models.Course
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self,validated_data):
        course = models.Course.objects.create(
            course_name = validated_data['course_name'],
            description=validated_data['description'],
            user_profile=validated_data['user_profile']
        )

        return course
```

My Viewset:

```
class LessonViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    model = models.Lesson
    serializer_class = serializers.LessonSerializer
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,BasePermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_current = self.request.user.id
        return models.Lesson.objects.filter(user_profile=user_current)
```

How can I get the desired result. I want to get the courses for the current user and show them as a dropdown list in my API view. Just only the courses that user created should be in the dropdown list not all.
OnetoOne relationship gives all results of course table.

Answer (score 0):

i think change your view code to :

```
    def get_queryset(self,id):
        return model.objects.filter(user_profile=id)
#You do not need to call it again when you put the Lesson on the model
```

\